# Unable to change language of app using createConfigurationContext()

Tags: android

I am trying to change language my app at run-time using the following code

```
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        LocaleList.setDefault(new LocaleList(locale));

        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

Than I override `Application` and `Activity`'s `attachBaseContext()`

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base));
}
```

The weird thing is that when I do these steps on a separate project the language changes but the situation on my app seems helpless.

I've logged if the locale changes on the activity's context object and it seems that it does correctly but still when getting string resource they do not get choosen correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

It turned out the problem was that I had the line 'resConfigs "en"' in the build.gradle which prevented the language change.

Comment: Create a base class for your activities and then store language in shared preferences and load on language store value and on creating activity load that language using value.!

Comment: Hi Helo, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Choose Langauge Activity

```
private LinearLayout llHindi, llEnglish;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_language);
    resetTitles();
    llHindi = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llHindi);
    llEnglish = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llEnglish);


    llHindi.setOnClickListener(this);
    llEnglish.setOnClickListener(this);
}



private boolean setNewLocale(String language, boolean restartProcess) {
    LocaleManager.setNewLocale(this, language);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

    if (restartProcess) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
    }
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.llEnglish) {
        setNewLocale(LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, true);
    }

    if (id == R.id.llHindi) {
        setNewLocale(LANGUAGE_HINDI, true);
    }
}



@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base));
}



private void resetTitles() {
    try {
        ActivityInfo info = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), GET_META_DATA);
        if (info.labelRes != 0) {
            setTitle(info.labelRes);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

LocaleManager

```
public class LocaleManager {

public static final  String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH   = "en";
public static final  String LANGUAGE_HINDI = "hi";
private static final String LANGUAGE_KEY       = "language_key";

public static Context setLocale(Context c) {
    return updateResources(c, getLanguage(c));
}

public static Context setNewLocale(Context c, String language) {
    persistLanguage(c, language);
    return updateResources(c, language);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context c) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    return prefs.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
}

@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
private static void persistLanguage(Context c, String language) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    // use commit() instead of apply(), because sometimes we kill the application process immediately
    // which will prevent apply() to finish
    prefs.edit().putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, language).commit();
}

private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}

public static Locale getLocale(Resources res) {
    Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ? config.getLocales().get(0) : config.locale;
}
```

global class extents Application

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base));
    //Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LocaleManager.setLocale(this);
    //Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: " + newConfig.locale.getLanguage());
}
```

this will works and you need to create different string.xml file for different language